# How to filter boolean value in strapi

Tags: strapi

I want to filter boolean values with strapi. I did not found any tutorial that show how to filter boolean value. Is there a way to achieve this? I tried but this didn't work.
`${url}/api/projects?filter=[featured][$eq]=true`

Answer (score 4):

Change filter to filters
${url}/api/projects?filters=[featured][$eq]=true

Answer (score 0):

for strapi 4

```
${url}/api/projects?filters[featured][$eq]=true
```

or

```
${url}/api/projects?filters[featured]=true
```

if you have more option for filter for example localization

```
${url}/api/projects?locale=en&filters[featured]=true

or 

${url}/api/projects?locale=en&filters[featured][$eq]=true
```